# How do i get a value out of an object in php

Tags: php, object

I have a php object and i want to get some values out of it

This is what i have:

```
$data = Array (
"title"=> "videotitle",
"filename"=> "test.mp4",
"description"=> "test"
);

$title = ???;
```

How do i get the value of title in a variable?

Comment: There is no such a thing as hash or JSON object represented with curly brackets in PHP. You should use array with square brackets to hold that data as [ "key" => "value"] and then access it as $data["key"].

Comment: That's not valid php syntax. You seem to confuse JSON with PHP Arrays and have written some invalid mix. I would recommend that you read the manual about [classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and about [properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: @harisdev there are php stdclass objects, I assume this was just a misrepresentation in code.

Comment: @Devon Correct, but, initialization of stdClass would be different than anything that is provided in question... I believe owner of the question wanted to use array as Magnus Erikkson mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick guide into php objects, because the notation you 've chosen should throw an error because php has no short object notation, like javascript or other languages have. Unknown, anonymous objects are somehow also unclean if you want to use them with respect to type hinting.

**The php standard class**

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->foo = 'bar';
$object->bar = 'foo';

$foo = $object->foo;
```

That should be the only clean way to declare a simple object. Sure, there are a few other ways and means, but unfortunately they are all messy and simply not standard with clean code in mind.

**Own value objects**

```
class MyValueObject implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function __construct(
        protected string $foo,
        protected int $bla
    ) {}

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }
}
```

This is constructor property promotion. This way of kinda short notation without defining object properties in the old way is available since php 8. You can access this properties as follows.

```
$object = new MyValueObject('bla', 2021);
echo $object->foo; // echoes 'bla'
echo $object->bla; // echoes 2021;
```

To get the object as JSON notation just echo it as json.

```
echo json_serialize($object);
```

... this will end up in ..

```
{
    foo: 'bla',
    bla: 2021
}
```

That 's it.